# Replace each occurrence of character/word with different word in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";
var stringArray = ["dashboard" , "dashboard" , "data"]
var replaceArray = ["https://abcd.com/login" , "https://abcd.com/home" , "https://abcd.com/data"]
for(i=0;i<stringArray.length; i++){
    string = string.replace(stringArray[i].trim(), "<a href='"+replaceArray[i].trim()+"'>"+stringArray[i].trim()+"</a>");
}
```

I have a string and 2 arrays like above. I need to replace my string with respective anchor link tags as mentioned in two arrays. stringArray defines the word to be linked and replaceArray defines the URL should be added. Like first occurrence of dashboard should be anchor linked with "https://abcd.com/login" and second occurance of "dashboard" should be replaced with "https://abcd.com/home" and "data" should be replaced with "https://abcd.com/data".

I tried to find out the word in string and replace it using replace/replaceAll, working fine for single occurrence word, but for multiple occurrences it is not working.

Anyone help me to resolve this.

**Resulting :**

```js
"Please click on <a href='https://abcd.com/login'><a href='https://abcd.com/home'>dashboard</a></a> and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the <a href='https://abcd.com/data'>data</a>"
```

**Expected Output :**

```js
"Please click on <a href='https://abcd.com/login'>dashboard</a> and then open the <a href='https://abcd.com/home'>dashboard</a> details to verify your details on the <a href='https://abcd.com/data'>data</a>"
```

Comment: You just need a loop and the `replace()` method. If you have attempted to write some code to reach your goal then please add it to the question so we can help you debug it. Also, your statement of `working fine for single occurance word, but for multiple occurances it is not working` - given that you're trying to replace the same word twice, how can that possibly work if the first replacement is global?

Comment: Try `loops` ...

Comment: What should happen if a replacing string contains a word from the list of strings to be replaced ? What happens if there are more occurences of a word in the data than in `stringArray`? Does a single occurrence in `stringArray` imply global replacement

Comment: Note: js `.replace(str, str)` only replaces the first.  Your need a regex with `/g` or use `.replaceAll` (it's unclear if this is the issue here as no code provided, other than the statement *works for single, but not multiple* implies use of .replace should be .replaceAll, yet OP states they tried .replaceAll)

Comment: Sorry edit the question with actual need, please check and help me to sort this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to solve this problem using the reduce method and a regular expression, where the regular expression will be the n-element of the stringArray array.

Through reduce, we will achieve that by replacing the word in the variable "string" at each iteration, for the next iteration we will already replace the changed value of the variable "string"

Solution:

```
var string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";
var stringArray = ["dashboard" , "dashboard" , "data"];
var replaceArray = ["apple collection" , "delta collection" , "data collection"];

stringArray.reduce((acc, stringRegExp, index) => {
    return acc.replace(new RegExp(stringRegExp), replaceArray[index]);
}, string)
```

Comment: You might not even need a regexp there... Replace can take a string too.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I hurried

Comment: @borshblack I tired like this but is not updating anyhting. I have updated my question now, could you please check it and help me..

Comment: in this case, you need to use the "replacer" callback, in which you get each match and use it in a template string as a result (a substituted substring) 
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-firefly-ny4ugy?file=/src/index.js